# Is there a good dupe target for the C++ problem of passing an overload set into a function template?

Tags: discussion

There is a problem in C++ that people fairly frequently encounter where they try to do something like this:

```cpp
template <typename F> void some_algo(F);

template <typename T> void some_function(T);

void foo();
void foo(int);

some_algo(some_function); // Error
some_algo(foo);           // Error
```

I have never been able to find a good duplicate candidate for this question. Is there one? Should I just write a canonical one and start hammering away at all the similar versions of it that I can find?

Comment: Writing a (good) canonical might not be a bad idea.

Comment: In worse case, your canonical would get closed as dupe of the hypothetical other, would probably still make a good sign-post.

Comment: How about this one? Seems pretty okay: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871381/c-overloaded-function-as-template-argument